# How can I create working buttons next to (and not below or above) a matplotlib plot in Jupyter Notebook using Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, button, widget, ipywidgets

I have 2 buttons and a plot, below each other. The code:

```
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

button1 = widgets.Button(description="Yes")
display(button1)
button2 = widgets.Button(description="No")
display(button2)

def logyes(b):
    print("yes")

def logno(b):
    print("no")

button1.on_click(logyes)
button2.on_click(logno)

plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.plot([1,2],[3,4])
```

The result in Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

I would like the plot to be placed next to the buttons, not below the buttons. I tried using [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/buttons.html), and changed the lines beginning with `axprev` and `axnext` to:

```
axprev = plt.axes([-0.2, 0.75, 0.2, 0.1])
axnext = plt.axes([-0.2, 0.65, 0.2, 0.1])
```

Getting the result:

[image]

This is the right orientation (plot next to buttons, not below buttons), but these buttons (`Previous`, `Next`) are not working in Jupyter Notebook, as they are not IPython widgets.

How can I create working buttons next to a plot in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Did you consider using an interactive matplotlib backend, like `%matplotlib notebook`?

Comment: Nope, I didn't, looking it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib and ipywidgets seems to come up a lot on SO. A common approach is to use an `Output` widget rather than plotting straight to stdout, and use the standard `%matplotlib inline` magic. You can manipulate widget layout using the `VBox` and `HBox` container widgets.

I'm not clear what you want your buttons to *do*, but this is an example of how you can layout widgets in the desired arrangement,

```python
%matplotlib inline
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

button1 = widgets.Button(description="Yes")
button2 = widgets.Button(description="No")
out = widgets.Output()

buttons = widgets.VBox(children=[button1, button2])
all_widgets = widgets.HBox(children=[buttons, out])
display(all_widgets)

def logyes(b):
    print("yes")

def logno(b):
    print("no")

button1.on_click(logyes)
button2.on_click(logno)

with out:
    plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
    plt.plot([1,2],[3,4])
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This can happen when the widgets extension is not fully enabled, can you follow the instructions here?

https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html